# Send an IOS image across an api

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image that I am trying to send to a rails app via my IOS app.

**Step 1:**

This grabs the image from the UIView

```
@IBOutlet var notifier: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var image: UIImage
@IBAction func Build(sender: AnyObject) {
    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image!)
    self.service.createNewImage(notifier: notifier, image: image_data!)
}
```

**Step 2:**

This is the service

```
func createNewImage(notifier: UILabel, image: NSData) {
    let dataDictionary = ["image_data": image]
    self.post("image/build", data: dataDictionary).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            if(response.description[response.description.startIndex] as Character == "S") {
                notifier.text = "This should be success"
            } else {
                notifier.text  = "failure"
            }
      }
}
```

This code currently causes the error:  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)'`

How do I package an image to send across an API?

**Notes:**

I believe the issue is coming from this line specifically:

```
    self.post("image/build", data: dataDictionary).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
```

post is defined as:

```
func post(path: String) -> Request {

    return self.post(path, data: NSDictionary())
}

func post(path: String, data: NSDictionary) -> Request {
   let  url = self.url_from_path(path)
    return self.client.request(.POST, url, parameters: data as? [String : AnyObject] , encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON,
        headers: self.getHeaders())
}

func patch(path: String, data: NSDictionary) -> Request {
    let  url = self.url_from_path(path)
    return self.client.request(.PATCH, url, parameters: data as? [String : AnyObject] , encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON,
        headers: self.getHeaders())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    let strBase64:String = image.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    let dataDictionary = ["image_data": strBase64]
```

You just convert the NSData which cannot be put into a JSON into a base64 string which can be put into a JSON